# Unable to remove a dead host from Ambari

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

We had some problem with a host and we had to shutdown that host.

Now, we are not able to remove that dead host from Ambari.

Whenever we click Hosts -> Click on the host that is dead -> Host Actions -> Delete Host

This host cannot be deleted since it has the following master components: DRPC Server, Falcon Server etc.

If I go to that service, all the actions against each services are greyed out. So, there is no way I can move those services to another hosts because those are disabled.

Please suggest a way ahead. Is handling sudden death of a service not possible in Ambari?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Ambari API as explained [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Using+APIs+to+delete+a+service+or+all+host+components+on+a+host). Some features of the Ambari API aren't implementet in der User Interface right now.

I remeber a case in my company where we couldn't remove a Node with the Ambari UI. With an API-Call like it's explained this link it was possible.